# Django Pagination: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am working on getting pagination working for my Django application.  The pagination works when I first load the application, however when I grab a new number of results per page value from a drop down menu and update the page any time I click the next button I get the following error:

> UnboundLocalError at /autotester/update_filters/
>   local variable 'num_results' referenced before assignment

Here is the relevant code:

in views.py:

```
def filter_report(request):

    # More code here with other irrelevant values

    if request.method == 'POST':
        num_results = request.POST.get('num_results_dropdown')

    tuple_table = tuple(table.items())    # table is a dictionary defined above
    paginator = Paginator(tuple_table, num_results)
    page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page = paginator.page(page_num)
```

in table.html

```
<form id="filter_form" method="post" action="{% url 'update_filters' %}">
    <!-- My other filter fields -->
    <div class="label">Results</div>
    <select name="num_results_dropdown">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
        <option value="300">300</option>
    </select>
</form>
{% if page.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">prev</a>
{% endif %}

{{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}

{% if page.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

my guess is that `num_results` is not being remembered, because when I tried to declare `num_results = total_testsuites` outside of the `if` statement it get's reset to `total_testsuites` and crashes because there is no page 2 any more.

Comment: num_results is a local variable in filter_report so when the request is not a POST request, the variable is not instantiated. Have you try using it as a global variable?

Comment: In a normal Python script that is exactly what I would do, well maybe not a global variable but I would pass it in to the `filter_report` function.  However, Django is different and I'm not entirely sure what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your form is being submitted using a `GET` request, which might be due to some weird Javascript submission stuff.
This is supported by the fact that if you set a value for `num_results` *before* the if statement it stays as that value.

Either way, your code relies on `num_results`, so be more explicit with it, eg:

```
def filter_report(request):

    # More code here with other irrelevant values

    num_results = 10 # Set a sane default
    if request.method == 'POST':
        num_results = request.POST.get('num_results_dropdown')

    try:
        num_results = int(num_results) # A posted value will be a string
                                       # if its not a valid int this will throw an exception
        num_results = min(100,num_results) # Don't let it be too big
        num_results = max(1,num_results)   # Don't let it be too small either
    except:
        num_results = 10

    tuple_table = tuple(table.items())    # table is a dictionary defined above
    paginator = Paginator(tuple_table, num_results)
```

Comment: I'm not at work now so I can't try it but I will try it first thing tomorrow morning and let you know.  However, I think I already tried something similar.  I can't find any verification of this, but I'm pretty sure anytime a page is loaded/reloaded that the entire `views.py` file is called and the previous values inside are reset.